# How do I call a jQuery function on multiple elements without writing it twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use JS to add class `.block` to a tree of elements, up to a certain point—stopping when it reaches the first `div` element.

If the user doesn't have JS enabled, the elements should not have the class; else, they should. That's why I'm using jQuery to add the class instead of writing it in the markup.

Here's what I have:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input .../>
    <time>
      <span class="js-block">Wednesday, </span>
      <span class="js-block">Sep 28</span>
    </time>
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to add class `.block` to both `span`s, the `time`, and the `label`, (and not the `input`), and **this works perfectly fine**:

```
$('.js-block').addClass('block').parentsUntil('div').addClass('block')
```

Now the duplicate call `.addClass('block')` doesn't sit well with me, so I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$('.js-block').add(function () {
  return $(this).parentsUntil('div')
}).addClass('block')
```

Am I using `.add()` correctly?

I have not tested whether this

```
$('.js-block').add($('.js-block').parentsUntil('div')).addClass('block')
```

works, because if it did work, it would be just as bad as calling the same function twice. The whole point is to not have repeated code.

Comment: Try `$('.js-block').nextUntil('div').addClass('block')`.. Also it will be useful if you post the `html` too..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao — I don't think `.nextUntil()` will work because I need to select the parent and ancestors of the element. `next` will get the siblings. Also, I updated my question; hope it's more helpful.

Comment: Oh, then fine.. So you want to add `block` class to `time`, `input` and `label` elements right?

Comment: _"But I want to call `.addClass('block')` only once"_ Why would it be necessary to call `.addClass('block')` more than once?

Comment: Do you mean use two different selectors to set `className`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume here that you have added the class "block" to each element

Then to access the class just use

```
 $(".block").click( .... etc etc
```

Comment: no, i need to use jQuery to actually add the class `.block` to the elements. my reasoning is that if the user does not have javascript enabled, the elements do not need the class. else, they do.

Answer (score 0):

> want to add class `.block` to both `span`s, the `time`, and the `label`, (and not the `input`)
>
> My question is asking if I can *reduce* the number of calls to only
>   one time.

You can use `:has()`, `:not()`

```js
$("div:has(.js-block) :not(input)").addClass("block")
```

```css
.block {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  div
  <label> label
    <input/>
    <time>
      <span class="js-block">Wednesady, </span>
      <span class="js-block">Sep 28</span>
    </time>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Though this solution works in particular, it is not ideal since it depends on the markup. If the `input` were changed to, say,  `select`, or, let's say more elements were added inside the `div`, then the JS would break.

Comment: @chharvey See original Question at _"Here's what I have:"_ What do you mean by the "the JS would break"? You can exclude selectors from jQuery object by using `:not()`; alternatively selecting only `label`, `time` elements using `:has()` `$("label:has(.js-block), time:has(.jsblock), .js-block)").addClass("block")`

Comment: What i'm saying is that your solution works for a very specific case. The js would "break" (a.k.a. not work anymore) if the `label` element were changed to something else or if another element were added to the `div`. A general solution would provide a way to select the `.js-block`s and their ancestors, up to the `div`, *without* depending on the markup.

Comment: @chharvey _"A general solution would provide a way to select the desired element and its parents, up to the div, without depending on the markup"_ Where requirement is that one or more elements within container would be excluded from resulting jQuery object, how would this be possible without examples of the possible  `html` markup included at the Question?, and descriptions of which elements should be excluded from jQuery object which calls `.addClass()`?

Comment: idk man, all I know is, if you keep providing solutions to specific, one-time problems, you're gonna be spending a lot of time writing a lot of non-reusable code.

Comment: @chharvey _"idk man, all I know is, if you keep providing solutions to specific, one-time problems, you're gonna be spending a lot of time writing a lot of non-reusable code."_ Not certain how this is related to actual Question: _"How do I call a jQuery function on multiple elements without writing it twice?"_ , _"My question is asking if I can reduce the number of calls to only one time."_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739435/how-do-i-call-a-jquery-function-on-multiple-elements-without-writing-it-twice/37739826?noredirect=1#comment62949817_37739435? Perhaps edit Question to add details

Comment: please stop quoting me

Comment: @chharvey Question is not clear, here. What is requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> For you particular situation use `.find('*')` then use `.not()` to
>   exclude the element you don't want.

```
$("div").find('*').not('input').addClass("block")
```

```js
$("div").find('*').not('input').addClass("block");
```

```css
.block {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  div
  <label>label
    <input/>
    <select>
      <option>Select me</option>
    </select>
    <time>
      <span class="js-block">Wednesady, </span>
      <span class="js-block">Sep 28</span>
    </time>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this.

```
$(".class1").add(".class2").click(function(){ 
     // do something 
});
```